# not a PNG file in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

In FPDF, I am using this function to print image on pdf file.

```
$this->Image("./media/logo_291.png",1,1,$image_size);
```

It's working fine in `.jpg` file. But not in `.png`. I checked on my server. The file is already there.
When I change entire image with .jpg extension, then it works but not for .png format file.

**ERROR**

```
FPDF error: Not a PNG file: ./media/logo_291.png
```

**EDIT**

I can see the `.png` file in my browser. It's just problem with `FPDF`.

Comment: You're doing `mv foo.jpg foo.png`, e.g. renaming the file? That doesn't change its type at all.

Comment: @MarcB : No. I am using different file.

Comment: What does `file ./media/company_branch_logo/logo_291.png` say about the format of the file? It might not be a PNG at all.

Comment: @TurboJ : This is .png file. I checked it.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the PNG file? The error raises because of an invliad PNG signature...